# Why do national libraries not seem to invest in good computer facilities for visitors?

Tags: library

It seems like city/county libraries are very much concerned with giving quality computer resources to library patrons, as are university libraries.

In Sweden and Germany, I’ve noticed the national libraries have computers but it seems like an afterthought. They are older and of a bit poorer quality. It seems like the national library is more concerned with archiving texts rather than being a center for patrons to study or read comfortably. It also seems the interior and the architecture is less maintained and more old-fashioned. This isn’t the case for the Black Diamond library of Copenhagen, with beautiful modern design but I don’t remember how the computer facilities there were.

So is it just a given that national libraries don’t prioritize usability for their user base in the way other libraries do?

What’s their primary function in that case?

Comment: Not an answer, as I don't have any concrete knowledge/evidence - but I would imagine the national library targets a different segment of the population compared to local/university libraries. Most people who need resources only available in a national library are going to be professional researchers who typically have laptops etc.

Comment: What's the relevance to academia?

Comment: I can't really answer, but guess that most national libraries are meant to serve other libraries and not the public directly. I'd also guess that most interactions are via correspondence, once literal, now virtual.

Comment: Why and how national libraries are funded and for what policies and goals is not really a question for this SE.  The answers will also be many and varied and likely involve politics and funding.

Answer (score 6):

It's been a while since I visited one, so I don't have any up-to-date impressions of computer facilities at national libraries. That said, they often are in historical buildings, as you say, and I also suspect they often prioritize access and visitors' comfort less than university or local libraries.

The primary function of national libraries is [typically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_library) to archive and preserve information, especially information published within the country. For this reason, national libraries usually have very large collections compared to regular-sized libraries. Along this line, the National Library of Sweden (Kungliga Biblioteket) [describe their mission as](https://www.kb.se/om-oss/det-har-gor-vi.html) [translated]:

> KB's mission is to collect, preserve and make available everything that is published in Sweden.

This is related to the concept of [legal deposit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_deposit), which goes back to 1661 in Sweden. Similarly, the German National Library (Deutsche National Bibliothek) focus on the archival aspect in [their online description of their activities](https://www.dnb.de/EN/Ueber-uns/Portraet/portraet_node.html).

> So is it just a given that national libraries don’t prioritize usability for their user base in the way other libraries do?

If they have a primarily archival role (as is commonly the case), I think it's clear they should/will prioritize that role first. The national libraries I have visited have done a lot in terms of usability for visitors interested in those archives - large preservation efforts to make manuscripts last for centuries, digitization, making available metadata, providing gloves etc.